# Can't center-align image

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems centering an image between two float-aligned pictures.

I can't add margin-left to the image in the middle. I would like it to stay centered on resizing.

[image]

My code:

```
#skjirt {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: flex;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid #662C49;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#skjirt1 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid #662C49;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#skjirt2 {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid #662C49;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#imageWrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add html code.

Comment: `float: flex;` is not a valid declaration :)

Comment: The html code is just then normal.    <img id="skjirt" src="image">

Comment: @JonathanHelding That's not helpful. Please post some HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the image blocks display in the middle then instead of aligning them using float, just center them by applying the `text-align:center` to the `#imageWrap` container. Also change your `display:inline` to `display:inline-block` so that the `img` or any other element inside the boxes conform and adjust to the parent width and height.

Below is a sample code using your classes and I modified it with the suggested solution.

P.S. The suggested solution also makes the boxes to be responsive. :)

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/wqjKoa

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped a lot